# Null property when accessing lazy non-nullable property of Android Sensor

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

When initializing a `val` of type `Sensor` by `lazy` the **compiler ignores that the value returned can be `null`**

*Note: The `val` is declared as **`Sensor`** and not **`Sensor?`***

```
private val sensorManager by lazy { getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager }

private val proximitySensor: Sensor by lazy { sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) }
```

`sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY)` can also return `null` and the method is not annotated with `@Nullable` So, it can't be checked at compile-time.

---

<s>Also, the **Android Studio** gives a **warning** when *checking for null* as we have not declared it as `Sensor?`</s>
[image: Warning message]

<s>**Shouldn't it raise a compile time error** when assigning a `nullable` to a `val` which is `non-null`?</s>

[Resolved](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)

---

When the value `proximitySensor` is accessed and if it is null, it produces a **runtime exception** as expected.
`'java.lang.String android.hardware.Sensor.getName()' on a null object reference`

`lazy()` in the Kotlin standard library reference as follows:

1. `lazy()` returns a `Lazy<T>` instance that stored lambda initializer.
2. The first call of getter executes a lambda passed to `lazy()` and
   stores its result.
3. Subsequently, the getter execution returns the stored value.

> Shouldn't an exception be thrown when the assignment is made and not
>   when we try to access it?

```
operator fun setValue(
                    thisRef: Any?,
                    property: KProperty<*>, value: String
            ) {
                // assign 
                // An exception should be generated at this point when the assignment happens 
       }
```

Comment: `SensorManager` is a Java class, isn't it? In that case the return type of `getDefaultSensor` is `Sensor!`, which has exactly the semantics you experience.

Comment: Because it is a Java API call returning `Sensor!`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ok. But the method `getDefaultSensor` can `return null` right?
Shouldn't the exception be raised when assigning `null` on runtime 
before we try to access it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik However shouldn't the exception be raised when a null value is assigned to a non-nullable one?

Comment: @m0skit0 But there's no assignment happening here. `lazy` is a _property delegate_. Its `get()` method is called when you dereference the `val`. However if you get `null` as the result of dereferencing `proximitySensor`, that would clearly be a Kotlin bug.

Comment: sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) doesn't have nullability annotation so Kotlin believes you regarding whether it can be null or not.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I agree but I think the exception should be thrown at the time of assignment not when we try to access it even if there is a nanosecond of a difference.

Comment: @harsh_v What "assignment" are you referring to? I don't see any assignment in the code you show.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think it means "time of delegation" where `proximitySensor` is "assigned" a `LazyDelegate<Sensor>`--Which happens at compile time.

Comment: @harsh_v Good edits. I've updated my answer about Lazy not checking if it returns null. You could consider it a bug.IMHO it isn't a bug, but it warrants further discussion.

Comment: @Aro Read your answer. Thanks for explaining so thoroughly. I'll wait and see if there is more explanation for such behavior before considering it a bug.

Comment: @harsh_v You're welcome. This question has been a learning experience for myself as well. Now that you've updated it a bit, what do you mean with your last code example of `setValue`? Lazy doesn't have that method so there can't be an assignment (since you can't `var settable by lazy {...}`

Comment: @harsh_v I've edited my answer to include a new (and better option) for resolving this issue.

Comment: @Aro by lazy { ... } performs its initializer where the defined property is first used, not its declaration, internally the assignment is done in a similar way a delegated property is assigned. `setValue`. I think we can say `lazy` is a special kind of predefined Delegate in the Kotlin API.

Comment: @harsh_v I agree, initialization happens when the property is first accessed. I wouldn't say this is special issue for lazy since any kind of delegate could share this issue (the issue of having it's generic type param set to a platform type). Also, you would have the exact same issue if you replaced lazy with a method that returned a platform type. I'll make some example code to demonstrate the same problem without lazy.

Answer (score 2):

### Should there be a Compile-time error?

> Shouldn't it raise a compile time error when assigning a nullable to a val which is non-null?

**Yes, but that's not what's happening here** In this case, you are assigning a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) to your value and telling the compiler to treat it as non-nullable. There should be a runtime error of `IllegalStateException`-as @MarkoTopolnik  points out, **this is a bug**.

### Bug

This bug is covered by [KT-8135](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8135). Here's a linked issue directly related to delegates, [KT-24258](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24258).
There's also a discussion topic with some runnable examples [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/delegates-should-perform-null-check-when-accessed/7853).

### When will the runtime exception be thrown?

The error will be triggered when you use `proximitySensor`in a way that requires a non-nullable value such as the following:

```
val s: Sensor = proximitySensor
proximitySensor.someMethod()
println(proximitySensor.someProperty)
```

But this will not throw an exception when the property is initialized! We can fix that...

### Why isn't there an error when the Lazy property is first initialized?

Since `sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY)` is implemented in java it returns a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types). Therefore, the Lazy delegate is of type, `Lazy<Sensor!>`.

The Lazy class runs the initializer lambda. The result of the lambda is saved and then returned as type `T`, which is `Sensor!`.

## Solution

If we explicitly declare the type params when calling the `lazy` function:

```
private val proximitySensor: Sensor by lazy<Sensor> { sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) }
```

Then an exception will be thrown as soon as the lazy value is accessed.

### Other options

#### Declare proximitySensor as nullable

The warning is steering you in the right direction either don't check for null or declare it as nullable. Tell the compiler the value should be treated as a nullable by explicitly declaring the type as nullable:

```
private val proximitySensor: Sensor? by lazy { sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) }
```

#### Provide a default value inside the lazy initializer

As you mentioned, `sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY)` may return null. We could return a default value:

```
val proximitySensor: Sensor by lazy {
  sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) ?: SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE 
}
```

### A note about Platform Types

Platform types in Kotlin make working with Java more pragmatic by allowing you, the caller, to decide if the type is nullable or non-nullable. The alternative of assuming everything in Java is nullable would mean you would have to do a lot of painful null checking even though the Java code never returns null.

*Note: If you're writing Java code, you can use the `@Nullable` and `@NonNull` annotations to provide the metadata to the Kotlin compiler as well as other static analysis tools. Libraries such as the Spring Framework [have done this to their APIs](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15540).

Here's [a talk](https://youtu.be/2IhT8HACc2E?t=5m43s) by Andrey Breslav, a Kotlin developer, that speaks in depth about this design decision of platform types for interoperability.

Comment: Here's a specific moment in the talk you mention: https://youtu.be/2IhT8HACc2E?t=18m8s. The silde says "`String <- String!` --- fails if the value is null".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, good catch. I'll have to look into the bytecode and investigate further then! I suspect, like `Array<String> <- Array<String!>!` it has to do with the delegation.

Comment: This is my intuition: the null check should be inserted by the compiler, but the `lazy` delegate works with a generic type whose upper bound is `Any?` and thus, for all it knows, is allowed to return null. Since this is not C++ and we're not generating code for each generic type instantiation, the code inside the `lazy` delegate doesn't defend against null, and it's just that code that's invoked on a lazy val dereference.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  I found this in the docs but couldn't understand it properly, maybe you can help. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Interesting. My understanding is that Kotlin checks for nulls only when it requires the type to be non-nullable (see my edits)

Comment: declaring ` proximitySensor: Sensor?` is a solution which I've used but it is quite difficult to keep track of every method.

Comment: @harsh_v Have you considered, `val proximitySensor: Sensor by lazy { sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) ?: "SOME DEFAULT VALUE" }`?

Comment: @Aro I'm left wondering what specifically you're pointing me to. In our case, `Sensor` is not a platform type, it's a non-nullable type. The value `null` simply does not belong to that type so if `proximitySensor` ever evaluates to `null`, it's not just an NPE, it's a type violation. Kotlin guarantees to always protect you from that by throwing an exception before you manage to evaluate such an expression.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Maybe I'm mistaken but I thought `sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY)` was implemented in Java? That return value is the platform type I'm referring too. So I agree, `proximitySensor` refers to a non-nullable type. And I agree it's more than just a NPE, I'd say it is an illegal state (`IllegalStateException`). I think the core of the issue is when to throw the exception, aka, when do we check the type and nullability? Currently, Kotlin checks when a property is assigned or is passed as an argument. Kotlin does not check when a value is returned.

Comment: Yes, it sidesteps the usual mechanisms, that's why it's an issue. `proximitySensor` should never evaluate to null, yet it does through this loophole. I think this bug will be difficult to fix, unfortunately. Ideally you'd be able to enforce that the type of your initializer cannot be a platform type. Then the initializer itself would be forced to do the check.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, this is a loophole. Reflection provides more loopholes to breaking typing this way. I think the safety-focused ideal is just to assume everything from Java is nullable (because it is). Platform types are based on the idea that it's impractical to make that assumption.    Being able to turn on warnings for treating platform types as non-nullable would be interesting. I'm not sure I'd use it a lot but I can see it being helpful in a number of cases.

Comment: Using `Unsafe.allocateInstance()` to create an object that violates nullability was the only thing I could come up with that completely breaks static non-nullability. But that beyond even the realms of reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your question this is now a [confirmed bug in Kotlin compiler's JVM backend](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24258).

---

#### Earlier Content of this Answer:

I made an MCVE with your problem:

```
val sensorManager = SensorManager()
val proximitySensor: Sensor by lazy { sensorManager.sensor }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(proximitySensor)
}
```

This is the support Java code:

```
public class SensorManager {
    public Sensor getSensor() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Sensor {}
```

And... guess what? It prints `null`. I call "Kotlin bug" :)

---

You ask:

> Shouldn't an exception be thrown when the assignment is made and not when we try to access it?

In the case of a `lazy` delegate, the only assignment happens when you access the property for the first time. This propagates to the `SynchronizedLazyImpl.value` getter, which contains the well-known double-checked lazy init idiom, and it is the only time the initializer block you supply runs.

Even without that detailed discussion it should be clear that the essence of the `lazy` delegate is to postpone initialization until the latest possible time, which is the first property access. A correct implementation would ensure an exception is thrown before the evaluation of the non-nullable property completes. The current implementation is, unfortunately, not correct.

Comment: This is a literal case of, "it's not a bug, it's a feature!". See this talk for more: https://youtu.be/2IhT8HACc2E

Comment: I know about platform types, but the conversion from platform type to a non-nullable Kotlin type is guaranteed to preserve the type safety at runtime. When assigning a platform type to a non-nullable type, there should be a runtime null check that throws an exception if the value is null.

Comment: This is not a bug. Null types are being checked but they are being checked against a platform type. The Lazy implementation is correct, but the type in this situation is `Lazy<Sensor!>` not `Lazy<Sensor>`. (See my answer above). Generics mixed with platform types and delegation had me running in circles for a bit.

Comment: The assignment from `Lazy<Sensor!>` to `Sensor` had to be null-checked according to the guarantees Kotlin provides. Failure to do so is a bug. An expression of type `Sensor` is guaranteed not to evaluate to `null` because `null` isn't even a member of that type. This happening is as incorrect as an expression of type `String` evaluating to an instance of `Integer`.

Comment: +1. Good call with the bug. For some reason I was thinking about this question and realized I was wrong about it not being a bug. Saw your edit after I posted this discussion topic: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/delegates-should-perform-null-check-when-accessed/7853